# Flutter Mockito Test Mock Failure

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, mockito, flutter-test

I am trying to mock a repository in my Flutter Widget test case but each time I run the test I encounter an error as shown below.

```
package:quiz_test/level/repository/LevelRepository.dart 6:23   MockLevelRepository.fetchLevels
test/unit/level/view_model/LevelSelectionViewModel.dart 46:30  main.<fn>
test/unit/level/view_model/LevelSelectionViewModel.dart 32:38  main.<fn>

type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<List<Level>>'
```

This is my test case (I will improve the test name later).

```
  test('Waiting for an interaction', () async {
    final mockLevelRepository = MockLevelRepository();

    List<Level> levelsList = <Level>[];

    Level level = Level(id: 1, name: "Level 1");
    levelsList.add(level);

    level = Level(id: 2, name: "Level 2");
    levelsList.add(level);

    level = Level(id: 3, name: "Level 3");
    levelsList.add(level);

    when(mockLevelRepository.fetchLevels())
        .thenAnswer((_) async => Future.value(levelsList));

    LevelSelectionViewModel levelSelectionViewModel =
        new LevelSelectionViewModel();
    levelSelectionViewModel.setRepository(mockLevelRepository);

    levelSelectionViewModel.fetchLevels();
  });
```

I appreciate at this point I'm not 'testing' for anything, I just want to get it to pass as is. Having said that I'm not sure either how to handle this since it returns a future.

As can be seen I've mocked the repository. If I put a breakpoint on the line `levelSelectionViewModel.fetchLevels();` it is never hit.

The entire file is:

**LevelSelectionViewModelTest**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:quiz_test/level/repository/LevelRepository.dart';
import 'package:quiz_test/level/view_model/LevelSelectionViewModel.dart';
import 'package:quiz_test/models/Level.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

class MockLevelRepository extends Mock implements LevelRepository {}

void main() {
  test('Test isLevelLocked returns correct response', () {
    bool response = LevelSelectionViewModel().isLevelLocked(1);
    expect(response, false);

    response = LevelSelectionViewModel().isLevelLocked(2);
    expect(response, false);

    response = LevelSelectionViewModel().isLevelLocked(3);
    expect(response, false);

    response = LevelSelectionViewModel().isLevelLocked(0);
    expect(response, true);

    response = LevelSelectionViewModel().isLevelLocked(4);
    expect(response, true);
  });

  test('Waiting for an interaction', () async {
    final mockLevelRepository = MockLevelRepository();

    List<Level> levelsList = <Level>[];

    Level level = Level(id: 1, name: "Level 1");
    levelsList.add(level);

    level = Level(id: 2, name: "Level 2");
    levelsList.add(level);

    level = Level(id: 3, name: "Level 3");
    levelsList.add(level);

    when(mockLevelRepository.fetchLevels())
        .thenAnswer((_) async => Future.value(levelsList));

    LevelSelectionViewModel levelSelectionViewModel =
        new LevelSelectionViewModel();
    levelSelectionViewModel.setRepository(mockLevelRepository);

    levelSelectionViewModel.fetchLevels();
  });
}
```

**LevelRepository**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:quiz_test/models/Level.dart';

class LevelRepository {
  Future<List<Level>> fetchLevels() async {
    final jsondata =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/levels/Levels.json');

    final body = jsonDecode(jsondata);
    final Iterable json = body["Items"];
    return json.map((level) => Level.fromJson(level)).toList();
  }
}
```

**LevelSelectionViewModel**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quiz_test/level/repository/LevelRepository.dart';
import '../../models/Levels.dart';

class LevelSelectionViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  late LevelRepository levelRepository;

  // ToDo - Need to identify how to watch 'levels' instead.
  bool changed = false;
  List<Levels> levels = <Levels>[];

  void setRepository(LevelRepository levelRepository) {
    this.levelRepository = levelRepository;
  }

  Future<void> fetchLevels() async {
    final results = await levelRepository.fetchLevels();
    this.levels = results.map((item) => Levels(level: item)).toList();
    changed = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // ToDo - These are hard coded for now... will change later.
  bool isLevelLocked(int levelNumber) {
    if (levelNumber >= 1 && levelNumber <= 3) return false;
    return true;
  }
}
```

Note:
I have tried adding
@GenerateMocks([LevelSelectionViewModel, LevelRepository])

just before main() in my test file but that did not resolve my issue.

So I have two issues here:

a) How do I fix the error? I can't understand what the problem is. I read that it could be about nullability but I'm not sure 'why' that is an issue here. The other potential issue was the type was wrong but I don't see that that's the problem here either.

b) Since the `fetchLevels` call returns a Future, how should I test that this method is doing what it should. Ultimately I think I'd need to perhaps 'watch' to be notified.

It's worth noting that I am using get_in and get_in_mixer. I am testing using Mockito.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, I can now answer the first part of this. In short I should have paid more attention to the Mockito documentation as the answers were all there.

a) I added the `@GenerateMocks` annotation

```
@GenerateMocks([LevelRepository])
void main() {
  test('Test isLevelLocked returns correct response', () {
    bool response = LevelSelectionViewModel().isLevelLocked(1);
```

b) I added `build_runner: ^2.1.5` to pubspec.yml

c) I ran `flutter pub get`

d) I ran `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`

e) I added the new import `import 'LevelSelectionViewModel.mocks.dart';` to my test file.

The test then ran to completion. All that's left now is for me to understand how to test this future.

I've managed to test the future by doing the following. Sharing in the hope that this helps someone else who may be stuck!

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:quiz_test/level/repository/LevelRepository.dart';
import 'package:quiz_test/level/view_model/LevelSelectionViewModel.dart';
import 'package:quiz_test/models/Level.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

import 'LevelSelectionViewModel.mocks.dart';

@GenerateMocks([LevelRepository])
void main() {
  test('Test that LevelSelectionViewModel level is correctly set', () async {
    var mockLevelRepository = MockLevelRepository();

    List<Level> levelsList = <Level>[];

    Level level = Level(id: 1, name: "Level 1");
    levelsList.add(level);

    level = Level(id: 2, name: "Level 2");
    levelsList.add(level);

    level = Level(id: 3, name: "Level 3");
    levelsList.add(level);

    when(mockLevelRepository.fetchLevels())
        .thenAnswer((_) async => SynchronousFuture((levelsList)));

    LevelSelectionViewModel levelSelectionViewModel =
        new LevelSelectionViewModel();
    levelSelectionViewModel.setRepository(mockLevelRepository);

    await levelSelectionViewModel.fetchLevels();

    expect(levelSelectionViewModel.levels.length, 3);
  });
}
```